# How to generate a proof of possesion for a X509 certificate using OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I need to generate a proof of possession, signing a verification code with my private key.

I did not find a question related to this, here in Stack Overflow, and I am not finding some reference on Internet. I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-security-x509-create-certificates#signverificationcode), but I want to use OpenSSL.

My verification code is related to a X509 certificate, like this:

```
7A69A4702DA903A41C3A5BC5575A8E3F49BEC5E5BA2D4CE1
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use OpenSSL?

Comment: I just do not want to use the script mentioned in the tutorial and I want to learn how to do this with OpenSSL, @Crypt32 . By the way, the tutorial says the script is based on OpenSSL. =)

Comment: Another reason, @Crypt32 , is that I am using Ubuntu. So, I want to do this using openssl (terminal).

Comment: Ah, ok. Didn't see that example is based on OpenSSL (weird).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the answer with the Azure support team.

I already had my root key and X509 cert, generated with the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout root_private.pem -nodes -out root_cert.pem
```

Then, I needed to generate the verification cert...

- Create verification key:

  ```
  openssl genrsa -out verification.key 2048
  ```
- Create the verification cert:

  ```
  openssl req -new -key verification.key -out verification.csr
  ```

When creating the verification cert, I need to specify the verification code obtained (`7A69A4702DA903A41C3A5BC5575A8E3F49BEC5E5BA2D4CE1`) as the "**Common Name**" certificate field.

Now, just create the proof of possession certificate with the following command:

```
openssl x509 -req -in verification.csr -CA root_cert.pem -CAkey root_private.pem -CAcreateserial -out verificationCert.pem -days 1024 -sha256
```

If I am not wrong, this last command signs the `verification.csr`, that has the verification code as the **Common Name**, with the root private key. At the end, the `verificationCert.pem` can be used as the **proof of possession**.

Comment: When i specify CN with some UUID, it automatically add "\x16" behind of CN such as "CN=\x16234234234234234". Do you have any idea?

Comment: @nolines , as you can see [here](http://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/lsp121/documents/ascii-npr.htm), `\x16` is the ASCII hex representation for the control character `^V`. I suspect you are using `CTRL+V` to paste your UUID. Try to use another method to input the code or type it manually.

Comment: openssl x509 -req -in verification.csr -CA root_cert.pem -CAkey root_private.pem -CAcreateserial -out verificationCert.pem -days 1024 -sha256
Changed from -verification.csr to verification.csr